# Break up graph into smallest sub-components of 2-nodes or greater

Tags: r, igraph

I wish to be able to separate my graph into subcomponent such that the removal of any single node would create no further sub-components (excluding single nodes). As an example see the two images below.

The first image shows the complete graph. The second image shows the sub-components of the graph when it has been split into the smallest possible subcomponents. As can be seen from the second image, the vertex names have been maintained. I don't need the new structure to be a single graph it can be a list of graphs, or even a list of the nodes in each component.

[image]

The component of nodes 4-5-6 remains as removing any of the three nodes will not create a new component as the node that was broken off will only be a single node.
[image]

At the moment I am trying to put together an iterative process, that removes nodes sequentially in ascending degree order and recurses into the resultant new components. However, it is difficult and I imagine someone else has done it better before.

Comment: You say you want the "smallest subcomponents of 2 nodes of greater", and that your example has the "smallest possible subcomponents".  But what you actually meant is the *largest* possible subcomponents such that the removal of any single node would create no further sub-components, right?  Otherwise you could just separate the graph into a collection of all of the 2-graphs.
I believe, then, that your problem can be described as finding all "biconnected components" (maximal biconnected subgraphs of a graph): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component

Comment: That is correct. Thank you very much that is exactly what I needed. igraph has the function biconnected_components(g). So i can use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want the "smallest subcomponents of 2 nodes of greater", and that your example has the "smallest possible subcomponents". But what you actually meant is the largest possible subcomponents such that the removal of any single node would create no further sub-components, right? Otherwise you could just separate the graph into a collection of all of the 2-graphs.

I believe, then, that your problem can be described as finding all "biconnected components" (aka maximal biconnected subgraphs of a graph): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component

As you said in the comments, igraph has the function `biconnected_components(g)`, which will solve your problem. :)